# Use Unity3D as GUI to a Win32 c++ with OpenGL app

Tags: c++, opengl, unity-game-engine, oculus

I have a Win32 app written in C++ that uses a lot of OpenGL code.
Right now we render all the GUI using OpenGL code, but I think using Unity3D as an interface layer would really simple things for us:

Is it possible to use our own c++ classes with OpenGL under a Unity3D app (in Windows?)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider an alternative UI library that is capable of rendering directly to an OpenGL texture without imposing the burden of integrating with the entire Unity system.

I've played with [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickrendercontrol.html), [CEGUI](http://cegui.org.uk/), or [libRocket](http://librocket.com/).

QML is the most well designed of these three, although it's support for rendering directly to OpenGL textures is relatively recent, so there are some minor gotchas, but in general it's easy to use and the limitations can be worked around.